# Mongoose not reporting error when db command cannot execute

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm testing Mongoose error handling for the scenario where the db command (save, update, etc) cannot execute when the connection to the DB drops either just before or during execution of the db command. In this example code:

```
var myModel = new MyModel(data);
myModel.save(function (err, newDoc, numAffected) {
    if (err || numAffected === 0) {
        logger.error('Error inserting message: ' + err);
    }

    logger.info('Message inserted');
})
```

If I put a breakpoint on the myModel.save() line, kill the mongod process, then continue code execution, nothing happens and mongoose seems to fail silently. The callback is never invoked and nothing is logged here or in the connection 'error' event listener defined as follows in app.js:

```
var db = mongoose.connection;    
db.on('error', function(e) {
   logger.error('connection error:' + e);
});
```

I would have expected some error message telling me the save couldn't be executed. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

I am using MongoDB 3.2, mongoose 4.5.1, express 4.14 and node 4.2.1.

Thanks in advance,

Fred

Comment: Are you passing the [safe](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#safe) option to your connection or schema? just checking, since the default should be  `true`

Comment: I'm not explicitly setting it so its using the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback isn't being called because if the connection isn't open when `save` is called, the operation is queued until Mongoose is able to re-establish the connection.

See docs [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#callback_never_executes).